# entity framework 5 install on win8 MSVC2012 RTM

Tags: windows-8, entity-framework-5

I have recently installed the Latest Win8 OS (RTM) and installed MSVC 2012 RTM as well (I also have MSVC 2010 installed as I am porting from Win7 Phone to Win 8 Tablet and need to refer to the old code (not sure if this may affect outcome)). I need to install Entity Framework in MSVC 2012 and when I look at the NuGet Package Manager it tells me version 5.0.0. is available. However it never installs correctly, it says it has installed successfully then, says it can't and uninstalls it. I have tried using the NuGet Package Manager and the PM console, the results from the PM console are below :

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework
You are downloading EntityFramework from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=253898&clcid=0x409. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 5.0.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'EntityFramework 5.0.0'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'EntityFramework 5.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETCore,Version=v4.5', but 
the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package EntityFramework
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

When I look at the packages folder during the install it all seems present and then it is deleted. I have admin rights set on my user Account.

What is going wrong? pls help.

Brenda

Answer (score 1):

You are adding EntityFramework package to Windows 8 Application or class library project (= to Metro application). That is not supported. You must use full .NET Framework 4.5 (= desktop application, web application, etc.) to use Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. This is what I did:

From the package manager console:

```
PM> Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Force
```

This threw an error. I then went to the "packages" folder under the solution folder and removed the Entity Framework subfolder. I then ran

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework
```

And then right-clicked my project where I wanted to install EF and installed it from the NuGet dialog.